# SQL Server - how to combine query and subquery results in a single node in a FOR XML PATH T-SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I want the following output

```
<a>
 <b>
  <c>
   <customer>Miller</customer> 
   <d id="21">Bike</d> 
   <d id="22">Helmete</d> 
  </c>
 </b>
</a>
```

I tried the following query (stolen from another stackexchange page and modified)

```
--Table for demo
declare @OrderTbl table ( id int, customer nvarchar(100))

declare @OrderDetail table ( ID int, fk_Order int,Item nvarchar(100))

--Load some data
insert into @OrderTbl select 1, 'Miller'

insert into @OrderDetail select 21 ,1,'Bike'
union all select 22 ,1,'Helmete'
union all select 23 ,2,'Bike'
union all select 24 ,2,'Helmete'

select 
 a.customer as "c/customer"
, (  select b.ID as "@id"
    , b.Item AS "data()"
  from @OrderDetail b 
  where a.id = b.fk_Order
  for xml path('d'),root('c'),type
)
from @OrderTbl a
for xml path('b'),root('a')
```

but it gave me the following

```
<a>
 <b>
  <c>
   <customer>Miller</customer>
  </c>
  <c>
  <d id="21">Bike</d>
  <d id="22">Helmete</d>
  </c>
 </b>
</a>
```

I kludged it for now by 
casting the query result to varchar and replacing the

```
"</c><c>"
```

with

```
""
```

but that is awfully inelegant, to say the least. Can anyone suggest a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close.  Just drop [customer] down one level of the query, from b to c

```
  SELECT (
    SELECT
      [customer]
     ,( SELECT
          [id] AS [@id],
          [Item] AS [data()]
        FROM @OrderDetail od
        WHERE od.fk_Order = ot.id
        FOR XML PATH('d'),TYPE
      )
    FROM @OrderTbl ot
    FOR XML PATH('c'),TYPE
  ) FOR XML PATH('b'), ROOT('a')
```